# Format String in Java regarding its length in bytes

Tags: java, formatter

Let's say I have a String containing non ASCII characters in Java and I want to use `String.format()` to set it so the formatted String will have a minimum width regarding of the string's byte length.

```
String s = "æøå";
String.format(l, "%" + 10 + "s" , s);
```

This will result in a string with 7 leading white space.

But what I want is there's should be only 4 leading white space since the original string is 6 bytes in size.

This seems to be a common requirement so I would like to ask if there's any already-built class that can achieve this, or should I go to implement the `Formattable` interface myself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A string doesn't have a number of *bytes* - it has a number of *characters*. The number of *bytes* it takes to represent a string depends on the encoding you use. I don't know of anything built-in to do what you want in terms of the padding (I don't think it *is* that common a requirement). You can ask a [`CharsetEncoder`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetEncoder.html) for the *maximum* and *average* number of bytes per character, but I don't see any way of getting the number of bytes for a particular string without basically *doing* the encoding:

```
Charset cs = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
ByteBuffer buffer = cs.encode("foobar");
int lengthInBytes = buffer.remaining();
```

If you're going to encode the string *anyway*, you might want to just perform the encoding, work out how much padding is required, then write the encoded padding out, then write the already-encoded text. It really depends on what you're doing with the data.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I am exporting the formatted String in UTF8 to a file and some kind of agent will manipulate the file regarding of the file size of it. That's why this problem raised.

Comment: @Quincy: But padding is usually done to give an appropriate alignment *in text* - if you're only padding to prevent the file from getting too big, are you sure you need padding at all? This seems like a pretty unusual requirement.

Comment: Sad thing is the client requires a line of concatenated fields to be split and read by their own tool. So we need to fix the length of each `field` on the line or they cannot parse the input properly...:/

Comment: @Quincy: Okay, so it sounds like you probably *do* want this - but I hope you understand by now why your thought that it's a "common requirement" may be incorrect :)

Answer (score 2):

```
String s ="æøå";
int size = s.getBytes("UTF8").length;
String.format("%" + (10 - size) + "s" , s);
```

Comment: Thanks, this kinda works but is not what I was asking. I want someone to confirm me if there's existing function as I mentioned. :)

Comment: @Quincy In what sense isn't String.format() an 'existing function'?